# Android mock location providers not cleaned from LocationManager

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I'm having an issue with mock location providers. I have an app that needs to get accurate valid locations, and I don't want the user to be able to spoof them. So I have a check for the mock locations enabled setting, which works fine.

However there is a problem with the location provider. If you enable mock locations, set a location with a gps faker app, then disable mock locations **and all other location providers**, the location manager still has a reference to the mock location provider. So although mock locations are disabled, the location manager tells me that gps is enabled, and serves mocked location data.

I know that you can clear test providers from the location manager, but mock locations must be enabled to do this

Anyone ever come across this, or have a work around?

Comment: Have you found a way to remove the reference if Mock Locations are disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I found a way to get an accurate reading whether GPS/Network provider are enabled or not:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
boolean gpsEnabled = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean networkEnabled = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've called :

- `removeUpdates()`
- `removeTestProvider()`
- `setTestProviderEnabled()` with false
- `clearTestProviderEnabled()` ?

Look at how [LocationManagerTest](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/cts/tests/tests/location/src/android/location/cts/LocationManagerTest.java&exact_package=android&q=class%3aMockLocation%2a&type=cs) does this.

```
// disable mocking. 
Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(),
       Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, "0");
```

Comment: The problem with calling these methods is that you need mock locations to be enabled for it to work.. I guess I could clear out the location manager in the onResume of my activities, but I don't want to be hassling the user to enable mock locations.

Comment: You can enable and disable this setting silently, see my edit.

Comment: Oh, cool .. will try this out when I get a chance. Didn't think you could disable system settings like this..

Comment: To do this I need the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission, which I won't be able to get my hands on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034160/how-can-i-get-the-dreaded-write-secure-settings-permission-for-my-android-app