# Change proxy from android app

Tags: android, permissions, proxy

I searched it over the internet and found [this link](http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/android-how-to-set-proxy-for-android-browser/). I followed it but it didn't work. So I looked at logcat which told me this:

```
Setting http_proxy has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, value is unchanged.
```

So I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

to the menifest and in my code, I changed to

```
Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:8080");//enable proxy
```

and

```
Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY, "");//disable proxy
```

but still I get the same `setting moved` error. What am I missing?

I saw the question [How can I get the dreaded WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission for my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034160/how-can-i-get-the-dreaded-write-secure-settings-permission-for-my-android-app) also which says I can't get this permission. Is that true? And come on, I'm just changing proxy setting! Why am I not allowed to do so? At least, can I direct user to somewhere he can himself change proxy, like we do for enabling bluetooth?

Comment: DNS resolving doesn't work behind a proxy.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2764.  from this link http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html

Comment: @Aditya: seems like that issue was for android 1.5. They must have resolved it till now.

Comment: It was still Open Issue. Similarly there is an issue with WiFi  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1273  Android seem to have some PROXY issues !!!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Settings.System.putString() instead of Settings.Secure.putString().  The String name passed in is usually "http_proxy" in both cases, the difference is you want to save to the Secure class' database.