# Problems with checking for WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission in my app

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to Android, and Javascript. But, I'm actively learning by watching tutorials, and asking questions. Now, I'm trying to code an app that changes certain system values. I know this can only be done by granting my app the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission. Through my research I've realized I cannot declare the permission in the manifest file itself. Obviously, the only respectable answer is to check if the permission has been granted by the user through ADB. I can't find anything related to this topic and I'm hoping you guys can help me come to a conclusion on how to properly do this. So far this is the code that I have.

```
package com.datastream.settingschanger;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String requiredPermission = "android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS";
    int checkVal = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission);
    if (checkVal == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS has been granted to the application. You may now continue!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (checkVal == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS has not been granted to the application. Please grant access to continue.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

But, when ever I run this in Android Studio I get the following errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol method getContext()
error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
```

Can anyone help me resolves these errors? I have no clue how to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The **`getContext()`** and **`getActivity()`** method is used in **`Fragment`** to get `Context`

Remove **`getContext()`** and **`getActivity()`** And use **`this`** and **`MainActivity.this`** to get `Context` in your activity

Use this

```
int checkVal = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission);
```

instead of this

```
int checkVal = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission);
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String requiredPermission = "android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS";
    int checkVal = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission);
    if (checkVal == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS has been granted to the application. You may now continue!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (checkVal == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS has not been granted to the application. Please grant access to continue.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy response, and help! That seems to have done the trick! But, I'm noticing that the toast messages upon app launch both display. To me in the code it appears that only ONE toast should be shown after checking for permissions. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: @DataStream3 check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034160/how-can-i-get-the-dreaded-write-secure-settings-permission-for-my-android-app

Comment: Thank you for the link Nilesh! The code works perfectly now and I have you to thank for that! Thank you so so much!

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you again. Can you help me with one more thing? Do you know how I can change the value of a string located in the Global table of the Android Settings Database?