# Unable to clear mock location?

Tags: java, android, location, android-fusedlocation

This is how I set a mock location in my app:

```
public void startMockLocation(String latitude, String longitude){

    FusedLocationProviderClient locationProvider =  new FusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
    locationProvider.setMockMode(true);

    Location loc = new Location("gps");

    mockLocation = new Location("gps");
    mockLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(latitude));
    mockLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(longitude));
    mockLocation.setAltitude(loc.getAltitude());
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

    mockLocation.setAccuracy(1f);
    mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mockLocation.setBearingAccuracyDegrees(0.1f);
        mockLocation.setVerticalAccuracyMeters(0.1f);
        mockLocation.setSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond(0.01f);
    }

    locationProvider.setMockLocation(mockLocation);
}
```

However I wasn't able to clear the mock location and set the real location back using this code below. What should I write instead?

```
public void clearMockLocation() {
    locationProvider.setMockMode(false);
}
```

Comment: the code is fine  can you show your code where you are accessing current location... ?

Comment: Did you get the necessary permission?

Comment: @PraveenSP I'm not accessing the current location anywhere.

Comment: @JavadDehban Yes, I did.

Comment: Dutch if you are not accessing location than how you know that the device is still using mock location ... even after setting mocking to false

Comment: @PraveenSP I know that it is in mock location because I'm the one who set it as mock location...

Comment: We are missing something here.....  again my question is how ? let me elaborate it now you set mock location using startMockLocation() so how do you know you have set it I mean there has to be someplace where you are seeing your current location which is mock ...so what is that place ... ? are you using other apps to check your current location...

Comment: @PraveenSP Yes, I'm using Google Maps to see the location.

Comment: so after you are setting mock location ... you are going to google map and google map is still showing you the location you set which is mock one ... ? are you enabled GPS when you go to google map ?

Comment: @PraveenSP Yes, GPS is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

---

As far, your problem is following these steps such as:

1. Setting your mock location for Gps
2. Going to GoogleMaps and see your mock location
3. Turn back your app and want to stop mocking

---

Here I am giving you some *techniques* to disable *mock locations*.

---

**Method.1**

Spoofing or faked locations can be avoided by using the Location Manager's API.

For this you first have to import the google play services `LocationServices` ([must visit](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/)) API:

You need to import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

And in App-level `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Your Class must implement these interfaces:

```
public class TestMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener { ...}
```

Then, you need to `Override` these methods such as:

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
```

Now, We can remove the test provider before requesting the location updates from both the `providers` (Network or Gps):

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

try {
    Log.d(TAG ,"Removing Test providers")
    locationManager .removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException error) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Got exception in removing test  provider");
}

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
```

Now, If you look into the Android documentation of the [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager):

```
removeTestProvider() throws 
IllegalArgumentException    if no provider with the given name exists
```

You will get a better intuition from this [android-issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36932813). For that specific thread, You can try using `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE` instead of `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` such as:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String locationprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

if ( locationprovider == null ) {
    Log.e(TAG, "location provider is not available.!");
    return;
}
```

---

**Method.2**

If the above method still doesn't work for you, you can silently *enable /disable* mock settings as follows:

```
// disable mocking. 
Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(),
       Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, "0");
```

You can also get better intuition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034276/10413749) and [here](https://bm.enthuses.me/buffered.php?bref=4710).

---

**Method.3**

There is another way you can do that to get an accurate understanding whether *GPS/Network* providers are enabled or not:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
boolean gpsEnabled = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean networkEnabled = Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

---

**Other Steps to follow.**

---

You should have to follow these steps to `clear/reset` your mock location such as:

- Enable mock locations in the development panel in your settings.
- Add permissions to your `Manifest.xml` i.e.

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />`
- Now again open GoogleMaps, and wait until the Gps provider to receive a new realtime-location. It could be a bit of time-consuming i.e. (`1-3 minutes`).

So while removing the provider, just let the Gps receive a new fresh location, then it will be resolved and fixed. If in case, it is not working again, then you can further do these steps:

> Go to the app settings, *Clear* the App-Cache and *Restart* the *Mobile
>   Device*.

I hope that it would work really fine. You can also visit these references to get better intuition:

- [Android-mock-location-on-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/android-mock-location-on-device)
- [Remove-mock-location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#removeTestProvider(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code doesn't always work because my app frequently crashes with this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown`

Comment: I have updated my question. If it's still not working then it's almost certain that you have no GPS provider enabled on your `device/emulator`. *It has to have this feature in order to even receive the mock locations*.

Comment: @Dutch I have updated my answer with the most possible scenarios using different techniques. Please revisit and let me know, how can I further assist you?

Comment: I get `error Cannot resolve symbol locationListener` after following method 1

Comment: @Dutch I have improved method-1 so that you can easily include location-listener API. It will resolve your error. I have given a reference in the recent update to give you a better intuition. Please *must visit*.

Comment: If it doesn't solve your problem, Then, share your complete code in your question. So that I can analyze. The given every possible technique is working fine for me, even I have tested on multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

as i see your code , you are calling two methods one to set mock location and other to disable it but in other method i am not sure which object of location provider you are using , i would prefer you to declare a global object of location provider and use it anywhere

```
FusedLocationProviderClient locationProvider;

public void startMockLocation(String latitude, String longitude){

    locationProvider =  new FusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
    locationProvider.setMockMode(true);

    Location loc = new Location("gps");

    mockLocation = new Location("gps");
    mockLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(latitude));
    mockLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(longitude));
    mockLocation.setAltitude(loc.getAltitude());
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

    mockLocation.setAccuracy(1f);
    mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mockLocation.setBearingAccuracyDegrees(0.1f);
        mockLocation.setVerticalAccuracyMeters(0.1f);
        mockLocation.setSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond(0.01f);
    }

    locationProvider.setMockLocation(mockLocation);
}
```

then in other method

```
public void clearMockLocation() {
if(locationProvider!=null){
locationProvider.setMockMode(false);
if(mockLocation!=null){
mockLocation.setLatitude(real_latitude);
    mockLocation.setLongitude(real_longitude);
    mockLocation.setAltitude(real_altitude);
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mockLocation.setAccuracy(1f);
    mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mockLocation.setBearingAccuracyDegrees(0.1f);
        mockLocation.setVerticalAccuracyMeters(0.1f);
        mockLocation.setSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond(0.01f);
    }

    locationProvider.setMockLocation(mockLocation);
}

}

}
```

Comment: can you debug and tell me what is actually happening ?

Comment: This just sets another mock location. That's not what I want. I need the device to go back to using the current location like usual.