# How to verify if android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS been provided?

Tags: android, adb

I have run in adb

`adb shell pm grant my.package.name android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`

And there were no errors in terminal. But how I can check if permission `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` via adb been granted

Comment: The fact that there were no errors doesn't mean it was granted. Try printing the result of last operation in shell and it will be an error code. Also: [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045283/write-secure-settings-permission-error-even-when-added-in-manifest)  [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034160/how-can-i-get-the-dreaded-write-secure-settings-permission-for-my-android-app) (None of them complete duplicates but the same "issue)".

Comment: @TheLibrarian how to print the result of the last operation?

Comment: `echo $?` but won't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
pkg=your.android.pkg'
perm='WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS'
adb shell dumpsys package "$pkg" | grep "android.permission.$perm: granted=true"
```

to verify the permission is granted for your package.